# Which measure gives this exterior measure $\mu^*$?

Tags: lebesgue-measure

Let $\mu^*:\mathcal P(\mathbb R^2)\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by $$\mu^*(E)=\inf\left\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty m(T_i)\mid E\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty T_i\right\}$$
where $T_i$ are triangles and $m$ is the Lebesgue measure.

1) Show that $\mu^*$ is an exterior measure.

2) Which measure is given by $\mu^*$ ?

**My work**

I did 1), and for 2), I'm sure it's Lebesgue measure, but how can I justify it ? Is the fact that a triangle is homeomorphic to a cube enough ?

Comment: Other than the very elegant solution @Surb gave, You can show that it does not matter if we calculate it with triangles and with rectangles, and the one with rectangles gives the Lebesgue measure.

Answer (score 4):

**Big hint**

Lebesgue measure is the **only one** invariant by translation.